# Obtener mediante awk una cadena que se encuentre después de un patrón determinado

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, grep, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un archivo .sdf sobre moléculas del cual paso a poner algunos datos que este tiene para ponernos en contexto:

```
$$$$

> <FORMULA>
C7H11N3O2

> <MOLECULAR_WEIGHT>
169.1811

> <EXACT_MASS>
169.085126611

> <JCHEM_ACCEPTOR_COUNT>
4

> <JCHEM_AVERAGE_POLARIZABILITY>
17.110928254345183

$$$$

> <FORMULA>
C3H10N2

> <MOLECULAR_WEIGHT>
74.1249

> <EXACT_MASS>
74.08439833

> <JCHEM_ACCEPTOR_COUNT>
2

> <JCHEM_AVERAGE_POLARIZABILITY>
9.059383875573541

> <JCHEM_BIOAVAILABILITY>
1

> <JCHEM_DONOR_COUNT>
2

> <JCHEM_FORMAL_CHARGE>
0

> <JCHEM_GHOSE_FILTER>
0

> <JCHEM_IUPAC>
propane-1,3-diamine

$$$$
```

Pues bien, me gustaría obtener solamente lo que se encuentra en el campo FORMULA, es decir,

```
C3H10N2
C7H11N3O2
```

He probado varias cosas y por ahora lo que más se ha acercado ha sido

```
awk '/FORMULA/, /MOLECULAR/' fichero | grep -v FORMULA | grep -v MOLECULAR | grep ^[A-Z]
```

Con ese código he conseguido mostrar por pantalla lo que se encuentra entre los campos FORMULA y MOLECULAR. Sin embargo, echando un vistazo a la salida obtenida en la terminal he visto que he obtenido algunas cosas que no quiero y esto se debe a que no siempre se cumple que el campo FORMULA esta seguido del campo MOLECULAR. ¿Habría alguna otra forma de utilizar `awk` para obtener el output deseado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución:

```
$ awk '/FORMULA/{getline; print}' data.sdf
C7H11N3O2
C3H10N2
```

La explicación:

Suponiendo que la fórmula en cuestión está siempre en la línea siguiente a aquella en la que aparece el campo `<FORMULA>`, basta buscar por ese campo y cuando se produce el *match*, ejecutar `getline`, lo que lee la línea siguiente. El `print` la imprime.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Igual me estaba comiendo la cabeza demasiado y era más fácil de lo que creía. Me informaré sobre el uso de `getline` para posibles usos más adelante. Un saludo!

Comment: En general, no suele recomendarse demasiado el uso de `getline`, véase [Is getline in awk command safe to use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139559/40596) o [All about getline](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline). Se tiende más a usar banderas para este tipo de tareas (rima y todo). Dicho lo cual, la respuesta es sucinta, cosa que siempre está bien con Awk, +1.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Gracias por remarcarlo. Era consciente de que getline tiene mala fama, pero en este caso tan simple me pareció apropiado. A fin de cuentas la mala fama se debe en gran medida a posibles "malos usos", pero este no sería uno de ellos.

Answer (score 3):

Es más rápido con Sed:

```
sed -n '/FORMULA/{n;p}' fichero
```

Esto busca un patrón e imprime la siguiente línea.

Con Awk puedes usar banderas para ver cuándo se encontró e imprimirlo después:

```
awk 'f{print;f=0} /FORMULA/{f=1}' fichero
```

Más y mejor en [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1983854) del gran Ed Morton.